# What kind of home flooring is this?

Tags: flooring, renovation

I came across a home in Westchester County, NY that was built in 1908. The entry, living room and dining room had an unusual flooring that I have never seen before. It is multicolored, rectangular squares that appear as if they are cork but much harder. It doesn't seem likely that the floor is original and may be over hardwood underneath. Anyone ever seen this before, know what it is?
[image]

Comment: It looks somewhat like Parquet flooring, but with different types of wood and different sizes, and the pattern doesn't appear to repeat.

Comment: Could be tile made to look like cork, or actually cork. (FWIW, cork can be quite dense.) If there are no seams, it could be marmoleum.

Comment: I’d test it for asbestos.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a patch work of “early vinyl tile” these type of tiles were reenforced with asbestos but the colors look a lot like what used to be available in the 40’s and 50’s from the homes I have worked on.

The photo looks to have a texture in the center but I think there was something on top that caused that.  the light reflecting off the floor from the door is smooth and that is normal. I call them asphalt vinyl because I don’t remember the correct name and they usually have a asphalt like tar for the adhesive that is really horrible to try and clean up.

Comment: My dad put tile like that in our 50's farm house. Only difference was the tiles were checkerboarded with light and vey dark brown tiles. He called it asphalt tile at the time. It was about 1/8" thick (maybe a little bit more than that). As I recall the tile was smooth and hard. Scraps of it would break when attempting to fold it over.

Comment: the texture could be from the underside of a mat

Comment: I think that is spot on wrt vinyl asbestos tiling. The texture looks like remnants of some kind of mat/padding. Seems like it would be a real hassle to dispose of and try to get to an underlying wood floor.